# DDD: Should 'country' be a Value Object or an Entity?

Tags: oop, domain-driven-design

'country': Value Object or Entity in DDD?

Opinions either way appreciated.

And, where to store the table of country names/codes?
DB?
XML?
In a class?

Thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If your domain is geographic or political, then it might be an entity, but in the average case, a country is just a value associated with things like addresses. In that case, in the context of your object model, it's just a value.

As for storage, the domain model doesn't really care. You can use the database if it's convenient, XML if you prefer, and a class if you have behavior associated with countries.

Comment: Well, I'm super late but how do you propose a value object to be 'stored'? I guess a Repository is out of question, static in memory values perhaps?

Comment: A value object is not going to be an aggregate root, so it's not going to need its own repository. If you're using an ORM, a value object can be mapped to composed fields in a table under a parent aggregate root, or even, under certain circumstances, separate tables under which the only meaningful identity is that of the owner object.

Comment: I have the same dilemma. In my case, I am using country as part of Address field. But I have a report where I need to provide a dropdown of Countries. The report shows Customers for the Country selected based on the country in the Address. I believe in this case Country should be an Entity. Am I correct?

Comment: @devanalyst I'd say it depends on if you have 1) much metadata about the country that you also need to deal with in your domain and 2) how much behavior is associated with a "country." If it's just a thing you sort and filter on, I'm not sure that's a strong argument for an entity (I sort, filter and aggregate over constrained values that are not themselves entities fairly often). But if you have other reasons for doing so that aren't just about constraining values or pivoting, or if you find it simplifies your domain logic, there may be a justification for it.

Answer (score 12):

One of the characteristics of an entity is that it has a life cycle, i.e. it changes over time. A value object does not. In fact, value objects should be immutable. So the question to ask yourself is, "Does the country object change over time?"

Another aspect which differentiates entities and value objects is that two value objects with the same properties **are the same**. So if you have an instance of country with the name "France", it's the **same** as another instance of country with the name "France", even though they are two distinct instances (assuming that's the only property of country for the sake of this discussion). Think of strings in most languages, the string "fubar" equals another instance of the string "fubar".

Entities, on the other hand, are distinct even if they have the same properties. One customer with the name "John Smith" may not be the same as another customer with the name "John Smith".

So given these characteristics you should be able to decide. Since there can be only one "France" and it doesn't change over time, it's probably a value object - unless your app needs to track more about a country which may change over time.

Comment: France is already at version 5.0: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Fifth_Republic ;)

Comment: To maybe clarify this a bit. We know that in the real world countries can change. For instance Czech Republic was renamed to Czechia. The question is does your application need to understand that that is a name change, or is it fine to treat the Czech Republic and Czechia as if they were entirely different.

If it's the former you may need an entity, and if the latter a value object.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine:

You have another entity - Customer.
Customer entity references Country object.
You have 2 entity instances with filled Country objects with same value (i.e. "France")
You are deleting country object from first entity (or first entity object)

- if you want country to be deleted for 2nd entity object too
  => Country is an entity object
- if you vant country to be deleted only for 1st entity object
  => Country is a value object